# Transactional wrapped method doesn't persist or remove

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a problem with a CDI Named Bean which is @Transactional.

I use the WildFly 11.1.0.Final.

Here the Code: https://gist.github.com/stefanwendelmann/7a1f8352900067d5a59826d6ee205044

This is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="QuoLoco" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Verbindung zur QuoLoco Datenbank</description>
    <jta-data-source>java:/QUOLOCO_NORM</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I call the method "doChange" and only edited Empfangseinheittypenparameter, the em.remove and em.persist doesn't trigger a flush.

When I call the method "doChange" and edited some of the main  Empfangseinheittypen empfangseinheittyp, I make a find on the Empfangseinheittypenparameter don't need a flush

What am a doing wrong?

Both methods are public.

Please see a picture of the Application attached

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If this is relevant yet. I did some tests with CDI-Transactional. There are no significant differences to EJB. Therefore a few questions: How did you find out, that the changes did not get flushed? What DBMS are you using? Did you call doChange in a subclass or from another bean?

Comment: Hi @aschoerk we use a SQL Server 2008 R2. The call comes from the xhtml JSF frontend. Now we changed to BMT to go along with our application.

Comment: Ahh SqlServer 2008, so no MVCC. But: How did you find out, that the changes did not get flushed? Did you call doChange in a subclass or from another bean?

Comment: No the doChange was called from the same bean. It (empfangseinheittypenparameter) got flushed when we edited some of the main infos (Empfangseinheittypen)

Comment: "called from the same bean" normally means, that the transactioninterceptor is not working. Are you sure, that it does?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, doChange is called from the same bean.
The problem is similar to [@Transactional method called from another method doesn't obtain a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109343/transactional-method-called-from-another-method-doesnt-obtain-a-transaction) which means, that the transaction will not end with doChange, so you can not expect a flush to be done when returning from the method.

Comment: I tried to annotate the methods with @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW) but got the same effect