# Whether and When Spring Lock Table if Method Annotated with Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional

This question comes from that, if I have a methodA, and methodB in classA like below

```
public class classA {
    public void methodA() {
        // some code
        ...

        // time to deal with db
        methodB();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void methodB() {
        // insert a record 

        throw new RuntimeException("testing");
    }
}
```

In **classB** Directly call methodA, there will be no transactional effect on methodB(this is to say spring will not rollback the insert operation even `RuntimeException` occurred).

When I move the `@Transactional` from methodB to methodA, and call methodA again, the `@Transactional` annotation works.

However, if I have really a lot of work to do in `methodA`, will spring lock the table during the total execution time?

Comment: That depends on your isolation level and database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will add a new class(i.e. classC) and move methodB(annotated with Transactional) to the new class as workaround.

It is the limitation of Springs AOP that `@Transactional` will not have effect if the method is called within the same class.
Refer to [@Transactional method called from another method doesn't obtain a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109343/transactional-method-called-from-another-method-doesnt-obtain-a-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't handle transaction by itself. @Transactional annotation lets Spring's proxy class to inject transaction begin and commit/rollback methods around your original method.

- Proxy wrapper will only be called if you invoke annotated method from outside the classes. Local method call will not use proxy class. So, call from method A to method B will not use transactional features.
- Secondly, Spring will simply delegate the transaction handling to underlying database driver. Whether your table acquires a lock or not will be determined by your driver documentation and (atomicity and isolation level) settings.