# Spring @Transaction(readOnly = true) propagation to threads

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void upper(){
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     executorService.submit(()->{
        lower();
    });
    }
    }

    public void lower(){

    }
```

I have above code in Spring. Does transactional(readOnly = true) is propagted to the threads in executor service and any DB modification in lower method are not allowed?
We are using Hibernate ORM and MySql database

Comment: entity manager isn't thread safe. you would need to create new one manually for every thread.

Comment: To my knowledge the answer is no. More importantly : why would you want it to be "yes" ? Wouldn't syncrhonization time on the same DB connection kill any gain ? Would it scale with multiple users as well as a Thread per connection model ? It's usually not that clear that it would. There is a use case for that, but it's not that trivial, so I'd think about it twice before using such a threading pattern. Not to mention : the hibernate session / EntityManager is not thread safe anyway. So unless you are fine with one Session per thread, avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not - it's per Thread basis. Also the thread has to be managed by `Spring` for this to work.

Comment: thread manager by spring means..?? The ExecutorService autowired into application by spring? If I declare a ExecutorService with a threadpool, transactional(readonly = true) will not be applicable?

Comment: @Pushparaj this is entirely unclear for me - the next threads will not even have the `@Transactional` properties - there will be no transaction at all... you would have to manually create the transaction inside those threads. May be there is another way, but I am not aware of it

Comment: if I mark  like below, the threads will get into transaction?


@Transactiona(readOn;y = true) 
public void lower(){

    }

Comment: @Transactionnal only works across instance/class boudaries. (You have to hit the AOP proxy, calling directly a method from within an instance does not do that) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109343/transactional-method-called-from-another-method-doesnt-obtain-a-transaction