# functional interface call within @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring

I have read this [@Transactional method called from another method doesn't obtain a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109343/transactional-method-called-from-another-method-doesnt-obtain-a-transaction) and learned that we can't call a @Transactional method from another method in the same class. I'm wondering if the following code works. I know that we can't put @Transactional on `doSomething` and have `doSomethingTransactionally` to call it directly, so I created a utility method that has @Transactional annotation in another class which takes in a function and execute it. The goal is to keep all the logic in the same class. If the following code does not work, is there a way to achieve this goal?

```
@Component
class A {

   @Autowired
   B b;

   public String doSomethingTransactionally() {
      return b.transactionalHelper(this::doSomething);
   }

   public String doSomething() {
      // a bunch of db operations
   }
}

@Component
class B {
   
   @Transactional
   public T transactionalHelper(Supplier<T> supplier) {
       return supplier.get();
   }
}
```

Comment: where is your question? and no - this is not going to work. You need a spring managed entity if you want _any_ Spring annotation to work (`@Bean`, for example). Read about self injection.

Comment: I didn't know you can't call a transactional method from the same class. I'm sure that it wasn't like that in earlier versions of Spring.

Comment: @JasperBlues you would be calling the proxy _directly_, without the wrapper that spring creates.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your response, I just updated my code, can you check again? I made both beans so they are within spring context

Comment: Ah yes of course. And from memory now - earlier versions of Spring *did* behave like this, depending on what kind of transaction interceptor was in use. The AOP weaver doesn't have this drawback.

Comment: Essentially, for advice to be applied, it has to cross the boundary of something that is managed by Spring. In this case, if you made a bean of some sort out of `a::doSomething`, _that_ would get advice applied, but not just `this::doSomething`.